# Using a string array to run one function multiple times in c++

Tags: c++, string, function, loops, constructor

Hello everyone im trying to build a program that ask for user to input multiple names but i want to create one function to do it all that way i dont have to do  cout enter first name, cout enter second name. In the process of writting this program i got stuck and my class is not being recognized and or running any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    //StudentMain.cpp
            #include <iostream>
            #include <iomanip>
    #include "Students.h"
    #include "Students.cpp"
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        Students Students();//("sue", "Jones", "3.2");
        cout << "Employee Info obtained by get functions: \n"
            << "\nFirst name is: " << _Students.getFirstName()
            << "\nLast Name is: " << Students.getLastName()
            << "\nGPA is: " << Students.GPA() << endl; 
        cout << "\n updated information\n" << endl;

        Students.print();

        return 0;
    }
    //Students.h
    #ifndef COMMISSION_H
    #define COMMISION_H

    #include <string>

    class Students
    {
    public:
        Students(const std::string &, const std::string &, float = 0.0);
        void setFirstName(const std::string &);
        std::string getFirstName() const;

        void setLastName(const std::string &);
        std::string getLastName() const;

        void setGPA(float);
        float getGPA() const;
        void print() const;

        //std::string firstName;
        //std::string lastName;
        //float gpa;
    private:
        std::string firstName;
        std::string lastName;
        float gpa;

    };

    #endif

//Students.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Students.h"
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

Students::Students(const string &first, const string &last, float gpa)
{
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
    setGPA(gpa);
}

void Students::setFirstName(const string & first)
{
    firstName = first;
}

string Students::getFirstName() const
{
    return firstName;
}

void Students::setLastName(const string &last)
{
    lastName = last;
}

string Students::getLastName() const
{
    return lastName;
}

void Students::setGPA(float gpa)
{
    if (gpa < 4.1)
        throw invalid_argument("GPA must be set below 4.0");    
}

float Students::getGPA() const
{
    return gpa;
}

void Students::print() const
{
    cout << "Students Information:\t " << firstName << ' ' << lastName
        << "\n GPA:" << gpa;
}
```

Comment: The first declaration in main is a function declaration. Move on from there.

Comment: SO is not for building your program for you. 

This is a template if anything. Show some progress and then I will help

Comment: You don't need to include both .cpp and .h. You should only be including .h

Comment: `Students Students();` ... Really? You also once refer to `_Students` :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of declaring a variable of type `Students` you're declaring a function `Students()` of return type `Students`. Small mistake, so easy fix:

```
...
int main()
{
    Students student;//("sue", "Jones", "3.2");
    cout << "Employee Info obtained by get functions: \n"
...
```